# How can I get different fields in a form inside a JSONField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm working on a web that needs to store data that can be changed inside a JSONField.

For example, my default JSON would be something like:

```
{
  "apple": [
    [5,10],
    [20,40]
  ],
  "banana": [
    [5,10],
    [20,40]
  ],
  "orange": [
    [5,10],
    [20,40]
  ],
}
```

Then my model would be something along the lines of:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    fruits = JSONField(default=json)
```

And the form that I currently have is:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = (
            'name',
            'fruits'
            )
```

The template is a little bit trickier but lets say I have a code that prints a textbox for every number in the JSON, like:

```
{% csrf_token %}
{% for fruit, values in user.MyModel.fruits.items %}
    <input type="text" name="{{fruit}}_0_0" value="{{values.0.0}} id="id_{{fruit}}_0_0">
    <input type="text" name="{{fruit}}_0_1" value="{{values.0.1}} id="id_{{fruit}}_0_1">
    <input type="text" name="{{fruit}}_1_0" value="{{values.1.0}} id="id_{{fruit}}_1_0">
    <input type="text" name="{{fruit}}_1_1" value="{{values.1.1}} id="id_{{fruit}}_1_1">
```

I haven't been able to change the values in the database. It doesen't show an error, it just doesn't work. The `MyForm.is_valid()` in the views file returns False

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to validate a form which doesn't have:

- a csrf token (unless you disabled it)
- exactly all fields declared in the `Form`, not more, not less

Here you either have to manually handle the form data or write a `Form` able to transpose your list of fruits to an object convertible into JSON before passing it to your model

Comment: Forgot to say it but my form has the csrf token. How could I transpose the list of fruits?